# Why does "prompt()" cause the screen to exit fullscreen?

Tags: javascript

I  my code you can enter fullscreen, and on a button click triggers a prompt(). But the prompt makes it exit fullscreen.

Is there any alternative or way to make prompt() not exit fullscreen?

Comment: Because browsers use a new window for the popup. The platform needs to exit fullscreen to show the new window because by definition fullscreen is for one window only.